# How to externalize the authorization of Microstrategy

Tags: authentication, sdk, microstrategy

Is there way to externalize the Microstrategy permissions in to XACML based authorization system? I guess, Microstrategy must have some kind of handler (or extension point) that can be implemented to call the Authorization system. Does Microstrategy contain such thing? If Anyone has done the externalizing of Microstrategy permission, Please let me know how to achieve it.

Comment: did you try to look into Microstrategy Command Manager to modify ACL on MicroStrategy objects? https://resource.microstrategy.com/forum/ReplyListPage.aspx?id=21920

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look for answers here first.

https://lw.microstrategy.com/MSDZ/MSDL/AnalyticsEnterprise/docs/DeveloperLibrary.htm

[image]